# Cannot find Symbol - Variable, despite the variable being declared

Tags: java, variables, methods, symbols, cannot-find-symbol

The numThrows Variable is inciting an error of variable not found when used in the main method. even though i declare it in one of the methods.
I use the declare the variable in the void prompt method. This program is designed to calculate Pi using random coordinates then uses a formula to estimate pie over a user given amount of tries.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Darts




 public static void prompt()
 {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many throws per trial would you like to do?: ");
    int numThrows = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many trials would you like to do?: ");
    int numTrials = in.nextInt(); 



    }


 public static double[] randomX( int numThrows)
 {
     int darts = 0;
     int i = 0;
     double[] cordX = new double[numThrows];
     while(darts <= numThrows)
     {
         cordX[i] = Math.random();
         i++;
        }
     return cordX;
    }
 public static double[]randomY(int numThrows)
 {
     int darts = 0;
     int i = 0;
     double [] cordY = new double[numThrows];
     while(darts <= numThrows)
     {
         cordY[i] = Math.random();
         i++;
        }
     return cordY;


    }
 public static void getHits(int numThrows, double[] cordX, double[] cordY)
 {
     int ii = 0;
     int i = 0;
     double hits = 0;
     double misses = 0;
     for(i = 0; i <= numThrows; i++)
      {
     if( Math.pow(cordX[ii],2) + Math.pow(cordY[ii],2) <= 1)
     {
         hits++;
         ii++;

        }
        else{
            misses++;
        }
    }

    }
 public static double calcPi(int misses, int hits)
{
    int total = hits + misses;
    double pi = 4 * (hits / total);

}
// public static void print(double pi, int numThrows)
// {

   //  System.out.printf("  %-7s         %3.1f            %7s\n", "Trial[//numtrial]: pi = "

 //   }


   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
    {
     prompt();
     double[] cordX = randomX(numThrows);
     double[] cordY = randomY(numThrows);
     gethits();
     double pi = calcPi(misses, hits);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numThrows is an instance variable to your prompt method. If you want to do what I think you want to do, make numThrows a static variable outside any methods.

It will look like this:

```
public class Darts {
    public static int numThrows
    public static int numTrials
```

These variables can be referenced from any method. This should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If `numThrows` is declared within another function, then its [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) does not extend to the main method.

Instead, if you want to use it in both the `main` method and the other one, make it a class instance.

For example:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static int numThrows = 2;
    public static void test() {
        numThrows = 4; // it works!
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(numThrows); // it works!
    }
}
```

Therefore, its scope will be extended to all the members of the class, not just the method.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the method `prompt()` it's unused, and put his block in the main method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
  {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many throws per trial would you like to do?: ");
    int numThrows = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many trials would you like to do?: ");
    int numTrials = in.nextInt(); 
    double[] cordX = randomX(numThrows);
    ...
```